# React Native Maps: Event listeners not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to fire off some event listeners so I can call an API once a user has stopped dragging their finger across the screen. I'm running react-native 0.32 and using the `react-native-maps` npm module. Below is the barebones version of the code I'm using, seems like none of the events are working like I expect:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#003D40',
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 65
    },
    map: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
      },
})
class Main extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            region: {
              latitude: 37.78825,
              longitude: -122.4324,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }
        }
    }
    onRegionChange(region) {
      this.setState({
        region: region
      });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView.Animated
                      region={this.state.region}
                      onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
                      style={ styles.map }                    
                 >
                    <MapView.Marker 
                          coordinate={this.state.region}
                          draggable
                          onSelect={() => console.log('onSelect', arguments)}
                          onDrag={() => console.log('onDrag', arguments)}
                          onDragStart={() => console.log('onDragStart', arguments)}

                      />
                 </MapView.Animated>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
module.exports = Main;
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Whats the version of react-native-maps you are using ? I think you are older version (0.7.1) which is incompatible with 0.32. You should be using 0.8.2. Check out these below threads for the problem caused

https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/issues/497
and PR in 
https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/pull/502